# Expected value of vitamins taken of the prefered taste

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

I saw the following problem [here](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section01.05.html):

> Ex 1.5.7. You and your spouse each take two gummy vitamins every day. You share a single bottle of 60 vitamins, 30 of one flavor and 30 of another. You each prefer a different flavor, but it seems childish to fish out two of each type (but not to take gummy vitamins). So you just take the first four that fall out and then divide them up according to your preferences. For example, if there are two of each flavor, you and your spouse get the vitamins you prefer, but if three of your preferred flavor come out, you get two of the ones you like and your spouse gets one of each. Of course, you start a new bottle every 15 days. On average, over a 15 day period, how many of the vitamins you take are the flavor you prefer? (From [fivethirtyeight.com](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/will-the-grasshopper-land-in-your-yard/).)

Here's how I tackled it.

Instead of considering 60 vitamins in a bottle and getting 4 of what's left, we'll suppose the vitamins are placed in something like a mini vending machine, which is clicked once a day and spits the 4 closest-to-the-edge gummy vitamins. In this way we can represent the vitamins as a string, which consists of 30 letters 'a' (for my spouse's preferred flavor) and 30 letters 'b' (for my preferred flavor).

For example, if the string is $abaabaabbaaabbbaaaabbbabbbaaabaabaabbabababaaabbabbabbaabbbb$, we can make it clear which vitamins are taken every day:
$$abaa\ baab\ baaa\ bbba\ aaab\ bbab\ bbaa\ abaa\ baab\ baba\ baba\ aabb\ abba\ bbaa\ bbbb$$
What will be important, is not the string itself, rather the 15 quadruplets, it consists of, and more specifically the number of each. Obviously, $bbaa$ is the same as $baba$, so each quadruplet can be presented as one of these five multisets:
$$M_1=\{4.a\};\ M_2=\{3.a,1.b\};\ M_3=\{2.a,2.b\};\ M_4=\{1.a,3.b\};\ M_5=\{4.b\}$$
Let $x_i$ be the number of occurrences of $M_i(i=1,2,3,4,5)$ in the string. The quadruplets of the example above can be written more compactly as a multiset of multisets: $S=\{0.M_1, 4.M_2, 8.M_3, 2.M_4, 1.M_5\}$. For a general string of 'a'-s and 'b'-s:
$$S=\{x_1.M_1, x_2.M_2, x_3.M_3, x_4.M_4, x_5.M_5\}$$
Two equations can be written right away:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=15\ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$x_1(4.a)+x_2(3.a+b)+x_3(2.a+2.b)+x_4(a+3.b)+x_5(4.a)=30a+30b$$
The former one shows that every bottle (string) is used up in 15 days, and the latter - for these 15 days all 30 vitamins of each kind are taken. The latter equation can be split in two by equating the coefficients of $a$ and $b$:
$$4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+x_4=30\ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
$$x_2+2x_3+3x_4+4x_5=30\ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
For every occurrence of $M_1$ I'll take two 'a'-s (not my preferred flavor), for each $M_2$ - one of each kind and for all of the rest cases I'll take two of my favorite 'b'-s. This means that I'll take $N=2x_1+x_2$ of the ones I don't like and $L=x_2+2x_3+2x_4+2x_5$ of my preferred flavor. Considering $(1)$, we have $N+L=30$, which means that counting $N$ is enough to solve our problem.

Now let $\overline{x_i}$ be the average value of $x_i$ after (infinitely) many 15-day periods, so it can be thought of as the expected value of $x_i$. Equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ can be rewritten in terms of the average values $\overline{x_i}$ (the proof is trivial):
$$\overline{x_1}+\overline{x_2}+\overline{x_3}+\overline{x_4}+\overline{x_5}=15\ \ \ \ \ (4)$$
$$4\overline{x_1}+3\overline{x_2}+2\overline{x_3}+\overline{x_4}=30\ \ \ \ \ (5)$$
$$\overline{x_2}+2\overline{x_3}+3\overline{x_4}+4\overline{x_5}=30\ \ \ \ \ (6)$$
Similarly for the expected values of $N$ and $L$:
$$\overline{N}=2\overline{x_1}+\overline{x_2}$$
$$\overline{L}=\overline{x_2}+2\overline{x_3}+2\overline{x_4}+2\overline{x_5}$$
We'll evaluate $\overline{N}$.

From now on, my solution seems too elaborate and brute-forced. I think there's a more clever one, though I have no idea what it is. Here's how I continue.

I consider every multiset of 15 quadruplets in terms of its $x_1$ and $x_2$ and count the number of such multisets across all possible 60-elemnet strings of 'a'-s and 'b'-s.

For example, for $x_1=4$ and $x_2=2$, we have 4 quadruplets with 4 'a'-s, 2 quadruplets with 3 'a'-s and 9 quadruplets with no more than 2 'a'-s. First, we have to arrange $4.M_1$ and $2.M_2$ in 15 empty slots. The number of ways it can be done is:
$$\text{ExternalOrderings}(4,2)=\binom{15}{4\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 9}=\frac{15!}{4!2!9!}=75075$$
All $M_1$ sets have only one internal ordering (as they consist only of 'a'-s), but for every $M_2$ set its elements have $\binom{4}{1}=4$ permutations and adds a multiplier of $4$. In our case $x_2=2$, so we can write:
$$\text{InternalOrderings}(4,2)=4^2=16$$
Now we are left with $\{8.a, 28.b\}$ for $15-2-4=9$ empty quadruplets. All of them are of type $M_3$, $M_4$ or $M_5$, therefore, in each of them, there should be no more than 2 'a'-s.

We now first count any placements of the remaining 'a'-s and then with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (IEP) the number of invalid ones will be found. First, we will place the remaining 8 'a'-s in any of the $9*4=36$ empty spots. This can be done in:
$$\text{RemainigAll}(4, 2)=\binom{36}{8}=\frac{36!}{8!28!}=30260340$$
ways. However, this number counts many invalid cases, where one or more of the quadruplets are of type $M_1$ or $M_2$. There are a few cases of these (only problematic quadruplets are characterized):
$$(1*M_1)\rightarrow A \text{ of these}$$
$$(1*M_2)\rightarrow B \text{ of these}$$
$$(1*M_1, 1*M_2)\rightarrow C \text{ of these}$$
$$(2*M_1)\rightarrow D \text{ of these}$$
$$(2*M_2)\rightarrow E \text{ of these}$$
Now, not all of these can be evaluated with ease, but here the power of IEP shines bright. We *can with ease* find the number of cases with *at least* $1.M_1$, the number of cases with *at least* $1.M_2$, etc. We do this by first finding external orderings, then internal orderings and at last letting what's left of the 'a'-s free. We calculate:
$$N_1=N(\text{at least }1*M_1)=\binom{9}{1}*4^0*\binom{32}{4}=9.1.35960=323640$$
$$N_2=N(\text{at least }1*M_2)=\binom{9}{1}*4^1*\binom{32}{5}=9.4.201,376=7249536$$
$$N_3=N(\text{at least }1*M_1,1*M_2)=\binom{9}{1\ \ \ 1\ \ \ 7}*4^1*\binom{28}{1}=72.4.28=8064$$
$$N_4=N(\text{at least }2*M_1)=\binom{9}{2}*4^0*\binom{28}{0}=36.1.1=36$$
$$N_5=N(\text{at least }2*M_2)=\binom{9}{2}*4^2*\binom{28}{2}=36.16.378=217728$$
I will show why IEP is applicible here. $N_1$ counts much more than the members of $A$ alone. It counts the members of $A$, the members of $C$ and the members of $D$ **twice**, so we can write $N_1=A+C+2D$. By similar reasoning we find $N_2=B+C+2E$ and finally the trivial $N_3=C$, $N_4=D$ and $N_5=E$. It's easy to convince ourselves that the number of invalid cases is:
$$\text{Invalid}(4, 2)=A+B+C+D+E=N_1+N_2-N_3-N_4-N_5=7347348$$
This is a direct application of IEP with two variables (in our case the number of $M_1$-s and $M_2$-s). The sign in front of $N_i$ depends on the parity of the sum #$M_1+$#$M_2$ - positive for odd sum and negative for even sum.

At last, we find for this particular case $(x_1=4, x_2=2)$ that the number of such 60-element strings are:
$$N(x_1=4, x_2=2)=\text{ExternalOrderings}(4,2)*\text{InternalOrderings}(4,2)* 
 \left(\text{RemainigAll}(4, 2)-\text{Invalid}(4, 2) \right)=75075*16(30260340-7347348)=27523085990400$$
What we now do with this huge number, is to multiply it by $(2x_1+x_2)=10$, as this gives the number of not-preferred vitamins of mine I'll take, if all these strings appear at some point in our random vending machine. Let's have a number $\text{NotLiked}$, which counts all such not-liked vitamins of mine across all possible scenarios for the pair $(x_1, x_2)$. The contribution in the case $(x_1=4, x_2=2)$ to $\text{NotLiked}$ is $275230859904000$.

When we run across all possible pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ and $\text{NotLiked}$ is evaluated, it will be divided by the total number of strings, that may appear in our vending machine. They are $\text{All}=\binom{60}{30}=118264581564861424$. Finally we'll have:
$$\overline{N}=\frac{\text{NotLiked}}{\text{All}}$$
It's evident how tedious this work is and it's almost impossible to be done by hand. So I wrote a program in C++ for me. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int d;

long long Power (int a, int n) //evaluates a^n
{
    long long ans=1;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        ans*=a;
    return ans;
}

long long Binomial (int n, int k)
{
    long double temp=1;
    if (k >(n-k))
        k=n-k;
    int j=k;
    for (int i=n; i>n-k; i--)
    {
        temp*=i;
        temp/=j;
        j--;
    }
    long long fl=floor (temp), ce=ceil(temp);
    if (temp-floor(temp)<ceil(temp)-temp) //temp is closer to its floor value
        return fl;
    else
        return ce;
}

long long Trinomial (int n, int k1, int k2)
{
    int k3=n-k1-k2;
    long double temp=1;
    int j=n;
    for (int i=1; i<=k1; i++)
    {
        temp*=j;
        temp/=i;
        j--;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=k2; i++)
    {
        temp*=j;
        temp/=i;
        j--;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=k3; i++)
    {
        temp*=j;
        temp/=i;
        j--;
    }
    long long fl=floor (temp), ce=ceil(temp);
    if (temp-floor(temp)<ceil(temp)-temp)
        return fl;
    else
        return ce;
}

long long IEP (int p, int rem_a) //p - number of free 4-tuplets
{
    long long ans=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=rem_a/3; i++) // i shows at least how many {3.a, 1.b} are there
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=(rem_a-3*i)/4; j++) // j shows at least how many {4.a} are there
        {
            if (i+j==0) //i=j=0 => this includes all cases (valid and invalid)
                continue;
            long long ext_ord = Trinomial(p, i, j);
            long long int_ord = Power (4, i);
            long long rem_ord = Binomial (4*(p-i-j), rem_a-3*i-4*j); //the rest of the 'a'-s can be placed anywhere, the IEP will deal with the excessive counting
            short int sign=1; // positive, if i+j is odd, and negative otherwise
            if ((i+j)%2==0)
                sign=-1;
            ans+=ext_ord*int_ord*rem_ord*sign;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

long long Number_of_Orderings (int x1, int x2)
{
    long long ext_ord = Trinomial(d, x1, x2); //external orderings of x1 * {4.a}, x2 * {3.a, 1.b} and d-x1-x2 with at most 2.a
    long long int_ord = Power (4, x2); //internal orderings of all {3.a, 1.b}
    int rem_a=2*d-(4*x1+3*x2); // Number of remaining (unassigned) 'a'-s
    //Checking special cases (which are easily dealt with):
    if (rem_a==0)
        return ext_ord*int_ord;
    else
        if (rem_a <= 2) //they are 1 or 2
        {
            int rem_ord=Binomial(4*(d-x1-x2), rem_a); //all remaining 'a'-s can be placed in any of the free spots left
            return ext_ord*int_ord*rem_ord;
        }
    if (rem_a == 2*d) //when x1=x2=0 => all 4-tuplets are {2.a, 2.b}
    {
        long long rem_ord=Power (6, d); // the numbering of orderings of the remaining 'a'-s ; 6 = Binomial (4, 2)
        return ext_ord*int_ord*rem_ord;
    }
    if (rem_a == 2*d-3) //when x1=0 x2=1 => one 4-tuplet is {1.a, 3.b} and all but these two are {2.a, 2.b}
    {
        long long rem_ord=(d-1)*4; //d-1 -> number of unassigned 4-tuplets; 4 -> internal orderings for {1.a, 3.b}
        rem_ord = Power (6, d-2);
        return ext_ord*int_ord*rem_ord;
    }
    long long all = Binomial(4*(d-x1-x2), rem_a); //all possible placements of the remaining 'a'-s (including cases, when in some of the remaining 4-tuplets there are 3 or 4 'a'-s)
    //Now whit the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (IEP) the number of invalid cases will be found.
    long long invalid = IEP (d-x1-x2, rem_a);
    long long rem_ord=all-invalid;
    return ext_ord*int_ord*rem_ord;
}

int main ()
{
    cin>>d;
    long long not_liked=0;
    long long all=Binomial(4*d, 2*d);
    for (int x1=floor(d/2); x1>=0; x1--)
    {
        int rem=2*d-4*x1;
        for (int x2=rem/3; x2>=0; x2--)
        {
            long long ord=Number_of_Orderings(x1, x2);
            not_liked+=ord*(2*x1+x2);
        }
    }
    long double ans=(long double) not_liked;
    ans/=all;
    double perc=(ans*100)/(2*d);
    cout<<"On average you take "<<ans<<" of the not-liked, which is "<<perc<<" % of all."<<endl;
    cout<<"On average you take "<<30-ans<<" of the liked, which is "<<100.0-perc<<" % of all."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program deals with the more general case, where a bottle of vitamins is used up in `d` days. In our case, the input is `d=15`. The corresponding output is:

```
On average you take 5.43228 of the not-liked, which is 18.1076 % of all.
On average you take 24.5677 of the liked, which is 81.8924 % of all.
```

In conclusion, $\overline{N}\approx5.43$, which means that $\overline{L}\approx24.57$ and this is our final answer.

As I said, this solution relies too much on brute force and I personally don't like it. Any suggestions for what I can improve are welcomed. If you cannot come up with something better, please upvote, so that more people can see this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: Hats off to the OP. I believe you got the correct answer.

Second: Simplification possible: Yes!

I will use OP's notation of a and b for the two types of vitamins.

Imagine lining up all the $60$ vitamins on the first of the month. On the first day the first four will get taken; on the second day the next four will get taken; and so on. But as you've lined them up in advance, it's clear that the probability distribution of colors should be the same for any given day.

Probability of $4$ type a vitamins: $\frac{30\choose 4}{60\choose 4}=\frac{63}{1121}$.  Note that in this case, $2$ type a vitamins will go to the "wrong" person.

Probability of $3$ type a and $1$ type b: $\frac{{30\choose 3}\cdot {30\choose 1}}{60\choose 4}=\frac{280}{1121}$.  Note that in this case $1$ type a vitamin will go to the "wrong" person.

Note that these two scenarios are the only ones where any type a vitamins go to the wrong person.

Now there are $15$ groupings of $4$ vitamins. So the total expected number of type a going to the wrong person during a $15$ day period is:
$$15\cdot\left(2\cdot \frac{63}{1121}+1\cdot \frac{280}{1121}\right)=\frac{6090}{1121}\approx 5.4326$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the probability of day 2 being, for example, of type $M_1=\{4.a\}$ is dependent on what has happened on day 1.

Comment: Yes, day $2$ does depend on day $1$, but the overall unconditioned probabilities for day $2$ are the same as those of day $1$.

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question, but how do you prove this? It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: see my previous comment, please.

Comment: @Veselin Dimov  With your eyes shut, arrange the $60$ gummies into a line. Cover them. Now open your eyes. There are a line of $60$ gummies that you can't see. What is the probability distribution of gummy types for day $17$  (or any other day for that matter)? (You're not allowed to look at any of the gummies as you answer this question.)

Comment: Oh, I see it now, thank you, @paw88789! Indeed, my question was dumb.